# replace NA with value of the previous row

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataframe like this one with a start and end month and year.

```
ID  start_month start_year  end_month   end_year
1   1   2018    5   2019
2   5   1981    NA  1999
2   7   1973    NA  1981
2   7   1963    NA  1973
```

I have several missing data for the months and would like to be able to replace them with values and have the dates follow each other.
I would like to replace the NA with the start month of the row before - 1, based on the `ID`.

For the date NA-1999 as it is the most recent date in subject 2 and there is no date after that, I would like to put a 7 for the month.

I would like to get something like this:

```
ID  start_month start_year  end_month   end_year
1   1   2018    5   2019
2   5   1981    7   1999
2   7   1973    4   1981
2   7   1963    6   1973
```

I thought of using this:

```
df<-df %>% group_by(ID) %>% replace(end_month = ifelse(is.na(end_month), length(start_month)-1 , 7)) %>% ungroup()
```

My " length(start_month)-1" argument and the replace function doesn't work and I don't know what else to do

I'm sorry if this isn't very clear, it's complicated to explain this in writing...

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Hi, 

judging from the title of your post, `lag` and `lead` might be relevant.

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html

Comment: As a side note – this method of imputing missing values is called "Last Observation Carried Forward" and it's best avoided as it can introduce bias, see [this reference](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26400875/) or [this one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4785044/) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to replace `NA`s in `end_month` within the same `ID` by the following rules:

- `start_month - 1` for any period which has a later period
- 7 for the last period in each `ID`

Is that correct?

If so, then this should do the trick:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(ID, desc(start_year), desc(start_month)) %>% 
  mutate(
    end_month = ifelse(is.na(end_month), lag(start_month) - 1, end_month),
    end_month = ifelse(is.na(end_month), 7, end_month)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>      ID start_month start_year end_month end_year
#>   <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1           1       2018         5     2019
#> 2     2           5       1981         7     1999
#> 3     2           7       1973         4     1981
#> 4     2           7       1963         6     1973
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

##### Data

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
~ID,  ~start_month, ~start_year,  ~end_month,   ~end_year,
1,   1,   2018,    5,   2019,
2,   5,   1981,    NA,  1999,
2,   7,   1973,    NA,  1981,
2,   7,   1963,    NA,  1973
)

df
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>      ID start_month start_year end_month end_year
#>   <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1           1       2018         5     2019
#> 2     2           5       1981        NA     1999
#> 3     2           7       1973        NA     1981
#> 4     2           7       1963        NA     1973
```